# How to add JS in footer

Tags: javascript, footer

i added code in my footer.php just before the  but the code is not executed. I know it's better to use functions.php but i would like to test like this for the moment... Could someone help me please ?
thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function () {  
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ console.log('insider');
            var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.team-member').sort(function(a, b) {     
                return  String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('lastname').toLowerCase(), 
                $(b).data('lastname').toLowerCase()); 
    });
    var container = $('.ulcontainer');
    container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    $('body').append(container);})
   }(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: I think theme you are using enqueue all js in wp_footer hook. Try to add your js After wp_footer and check it.

Comment: sorry but i put direly in footer.php before </body> and jQuery(document).ready(function() is not executed

Comment: here it works without adding JS in settings but when adding jQuery it does not work anymore ...https://jsfiddle.net/xo5nopyx/

Answer (score 5):

### By Using wp_enqueue_script()

You can add your scripts to a JS file and then enqueue it properly. I assume you have added your scripts to `file.js`. Here's how you enqueue it in the footer:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_script_callback');
function my_script_callback(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-script',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/folder/file.js',
        array(jquery),
        null,
        true
    );
}
```

The last argument in [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) determines whether your script should be enqueued in the footer or not.

The 3rd argument is optional, and is an array of dependencies.

### By Using `wp_footer()`

You can also directly print your scripts in the footer, which is not always the best idea. However, this is how you do it:

```
function my_script() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Your code here
    </script><?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_script' );
```

Not that you have to wait for jQuery to be ready in such a method. You can enqueue jQuery if not already enqueue, by using this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'enqueue_jquery' )
function enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Comment: thanks but first i would like to know why this script is not executed directly in footer

Comment: What error do you receive? It's probably because jQuery isn't available at that point

Comment: no error but console.log('insider') is not traced. I thought with ONLOAD i was sure that Jquery would be loaded.

Comment: Maybe you don't have jQuery enqueued. Debugging such an issue is hard to tell without actually seeing what's going on

Comment: does it exist a variable that indicates if Jquery is loaded that i could trace ?

Comment: here it works without adding JS in settings but when adding jQuery it does not work anymore ...https://jsfiddle.net/xo5nopyx/